# Update Table A from loop data on table B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update table `qcard` with data every record from q_id table

*q_id table field and have 5 record*

```
--------------- 
q_id  groupcode
----  ---------
1     A01
2     A02
3     A03
4     A05
5     A06
```

qcard table now have data in field qcard 10001-2000
field loop q_id groupcode not data

```
qcard    loop  q_id    groupcode
-----    ----  ----    ---------
10001    
10002    
10003    
10004   
10005    
10006    
10007    
10008    
10009   
10010
```

I need to update qcard table with all record from q_id table for each loop (loop I set from 01,02,03,....to 99) if finish each loop have all record from q_id table

if works qcard table this data

```
-------------------------------
qcard   loop  q_id    groupcode
 -----   ----  ----    ---------
 10001   01   1      A01
 10002   01   2      A02
 10003   01   3      A03
 10004   01   4      A04
 10005   01   5      A05
 10006   02   1      A01
 10007   02   2      A02
 10008   02   3      A03
 10009   02   4      A04
 10010   02   5      A05
 ...... untill
 1xxxx   99    1     A01
 1xxxx   99    2     A02
 1xxxx   99    3     A03
 1xxxx   99    4     A04
 1xxxx   99    5     A05
```

Comment: You can use `ctrl+k` to format to code

Comment: Please check this link to know more on how to improve your questions going forward.https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer,

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers(N INT)

INSERT INTO #NUMBERS(N)
SELECT TOP 495 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.NUMBER) AS N
FROM   MASTER..spt_values T1 
       CROSS JOIN MASTER..spt_values t2

SELECT N,CASE WHEN LEN(CAST((N+4)/5 as VARCHAR))<2 THEN '0'+CAST((N+4)/5 as VARCHAR) ELSE CAST((N+4)/5 as VARCHAR) END[Loop]
    ,CASE WHEN N%10 in(1,6) THEN 1 WHEN N%10 in(2,7) THEN 2 WHEN N%10 in(3,8) THEN 3 WHEN N%10 in(4,9) THEN 4 WHEN N%10 in(5,0) THEN 5 END q_id 
from #Numbers

UPDATE A SET A.Loop=B.Loop, AND A.q_id=B.q_id
FROM qcard A,#Numbers B
WHERE (A.qcard%10000)=B.N

UPDATE B
SET B.groupcode=A.groupcode
FROM q_id A,qcard B
WHERE A.q_id=B.q_id

DROP TABLE #Numbers
```

Comment: sorry...in qcard table now have qcard field only running 10001,10002, 10003,......>>> 20000 .  I want to update field loop,q_id,groupcode on table qcard with all record from q_id table . I set loop is 01,02,03,.... >> 99 on each loop have all record from q_id ... 1 loop have 5 reccord

Comment: Are you try this? Is it helpful or not?